# Should a VS Angular web app include web api or not?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I am currently building an angular web app (old dog, new tricks) along with a Xamarin forms cross platform app. Both will connect to the same database via web api. My question should be pretty simple to answer but should the web api be part of the same web app project or would it be better to have separate project in the same solution? What is the best practice here? If they are in the same project and I debug through visual studio will the end points be available in that session or will it only be running the angular front end?

I know it seems to be very common for the api to be done in vs and the angular front end in vs code? But I really wonder if it is possible to include the API in a ve .NET Core web app or if there is something that makes this a terrible idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Separate your presentation layer from the business logic. When your webapi and webapp are independent you can upgrade them, change the technologies without worrying about the other part

Comment: I don't really see a reason off the top of my head why this would make a difference. I could add a new front end to the project or as a new project in that solution and abandon the angular front end. I could also leave the front end how it is and use a different back end with it. By default an angular web app does separate the presentation from the logic doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really receive much as an answer to this question. However I tried a bunch of times to access the API end points when running the Angular frontend and it did not appear that the end points were accessible so I moved the API into a different project inside the same solution. I can deploy the API project to be able to test the angular front end or send requests from postman to the API running in IIS Express on my development machine. I am happy with the way it is working now.